# How to install pandas using pip in python 3.10.3 in cmd?

Tags: python, pandas, cmd, pip, fatal-error

```
C:\Users\Sriram A>pip install pandas
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process 
using '"C:\Python39\python.exe"  
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe"
```

install pandas': The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Your question body states, "The system cannot find the file specified", yet your output shows, "Unable to create process". Can you please clarify your question and information, by using the [edit] facility. I note also that you are using a 32-bit version of `pip.exe`, so please be certain that you're not trying to access 64-bit processes or locations from the wrong architecture.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+Fatal+error+in+launcher%3A+Unable+to+create+process+using

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you also installed the python launcher py you will automaitcally run the latest version of python installed with:

```
py -m pip install pandas
```

If you want a specific version, you can run:

```
py -3.10 -m pip install pandas
```

To see all installed python versions included in your py-launcher, simply run `py -0`.

If not using the py-launcher you can run:

```
pip3.10 install pandas
```

To choose the specific python version for installing packages.

Answer (score -1):

Set the Environment variable for Python then you won't have go to the specified location.